# How to debug PHP in Notepad++ with DBGp plugin

Tags: php, debugging, notepad++

I am using chrome and mozilla. My editor is Notepad++. I just try to setup a debugger for php. I have followed [this link](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/debug_php_with_xdebug.php) and [this link](http://thecancerus.com/debugging-php-using-xdebug-and-notepad-part-i/)

I found it from SO answers. My steps are

```
Downloaded `php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll` and placed inside `php\ext`.

Added the following lines in `php.ini`
 zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll
 xdebug.remote_enable=1
 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
 xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
 xdebug.remote_port=9000
 xdebug.remote_mode=req
 xdebug.idekey=default
 xdebug.remote_log="c:\temp\xdebug\xdebug.log"
 xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
 xdebug.show_local_vars=9
 xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
 xdebug.trace_format=0
 xdebug.profiler_enable  = 1
 xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:\temp\xdebug"
```

Created `xdebug` folder in `temp`. My system is windows 64 bit. Php version is 5.6.2. [Restarted Apache - no error]

```
Then downloaded DBGp plugin and placed dll file inside plugins directory of Notepad++;
[Restarted Npp]
plugins->DBGp -> Config

  127.0.0.1    EMPTY    htdocspath     htdocs path
```

htdocs path is c:\Users\me\Server\Apache24\htdocs

Set breakpoints and started my page with the paramaeter `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=debugMe`

But it doesn't stop at my break points.

How do i solve this or My ultimate aim is to debug step by step PHP. What are the other options.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure of notepad, but I have tried this on netbeans and works ok.

Tip: I tried to use this debugger with netbeans in real projects but sincerely is better do this step by step.

I also use FirebugPHP in console this option is the best for me because does not disturb the view

Following links maybe help you:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

http://www.firephp.org/

https://enboliviacom.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/analizar-el-rendimiento-de-las-consultas-sql-en-aplicaciones-php-con-firephp/

Answer (score 0):

I found it worked when I gave the full path of the dll in php.ini

`zend_extension="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.6-5.3-vc9.dll"`

I take it you are also setting breakpoints with the DBGp plugin in Notepad - gives red dot in margin. What I also found is that when the debug stops at the line, the green arrow to show the current line is under the red dot and not that obvious.

EDIT: 
Use of session.save_path setting also affects DBGp, it only works on the last site mentioned. Therefore make sure the localhost root is mentioned last:

```
;Application xyz must keep session variables separate
[PATH=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xyz]
session.save_path = "C:\temp\xyz"
;...etc

;Must have this for DBGp to function on all localhost sites
[PATH=C:\inetpub\wwwroot]
session.save_path = "C:\temp"
```

Comment: Let Me Try This :) Thanks

Comment: It worked brilliantly for a while, then Notepad was updated and it no longer worked. Upgraded PHP from 5.3 to 5.6 because XDebug wizard said less than 5.4 not supported. Made no difference.  I give up. Trying 5.6 phpdbg interactive debugger now.

Comment: Actually the easiest is to use CodeLobster to do debugging. Even if you don't use it as an IDE, its debugging works well, not fragile like DBGp.